# Problem selfhosting ASPNET core 5.0 Web API in windows service

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-core, windows-services, self-hosting

I've got a problem on hosting a asp.net core 5 rest service in a windows service worker.
The service is running and i can call a GET method on my controller via webbrowser.
But when i try the same with postman or from a .net core 5 client with HttpClient i allways get errors.

The error messages didn't give any closer information to me for locating the problem.

I'm using Serilog for logging and i included the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App

Calling from any Webbrowser:

> OK

Calling the endpoint from Postman:

> Error: read ECONNRESET

Postman is configured with standard HttpHeader variables, which works fine, when hosting the same service in IIS. But unfortunately not within self hosting service.

Calling from HttpClient:

> One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.)
> -> The call does not reach the controller endpoint.

The WorkerService Program.cs looks like this:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var logPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "std.log");

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.File(logPath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Month)
            .CreateLogger();

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<SsmWorker>();
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

The Startup.cs looks like this:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            try
            {
                //services.AddControllers();
                services.AddMvcCore();

                //services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                //{
                //    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WebCommand", Version = "v1" });
                //});
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error in ConfigureServices.", ex);
            }
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseSwagger();
                //app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebCommand v1"));
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            //app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

The call from the console client app looks like this:

```
private void HandleGetInfo()
        {
            using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
                using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                {
                    var httpResponseTask = client.GetAsync("https://localhost:5101/ssm/info", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                    httpResponseTask.Wait();

                    var httpResponse = httpResponseTask.Result;

                    var contentTask = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    contentTask.Wait();

                    var content = contentTask.Result;

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    ConsoleHelper.WriteLineColored("Response: ", ConsoleColor.Green);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine(content);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
        }
```

The same configuration works fine in all situations, when i host the service via IIS.

Any ideas what can be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The issue is, that kestrel can't handle Postman calls or calls from HttpClient with http1 if the server is configured for http2 only connection over TLS.

My first approach in the appsettings.json was this:

```
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "http2"
    },
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5100"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5101"
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Subject": "mycert.de",
        "Store": "My",
        "Location": "LocalMachine",
        "AllowInvalid": true
      }
    }
  }
```

After changing the Protocols to "Http1AndHttp2" everythings works as expected.

But even I don't know why the same confguration works when hosting in IIS.